# How to select only columns with not null values sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has several columns, which can be null or have a value. I would like to get just those columns with a value.

I tried with an `IF` in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT
    IF(column1 IS NOT NULL, column1, null AS value,
    IF(column2 IS NOT NULL, column2, null AS value,
    IF(column3 IS NOT NULL, column3, null AS value,
    IF(column4 IS NOT NULL, column4, null AS value,
    IF(column5 IS NOT NULL, column5, null AS value,
    IF(column6 IS NOT NULL, column6, null) AS value
FROM
    table1;
```

but this is not the result I want because of what I explained in the beginning.
I also tried with a `CASE` but same result.​

Edit:

For example, lets say we have this table.
Column1 will always be showed.

```
COLUMN1  COLUMN2  COLUMN3  COLUMN4  COLUMN 5
--------------------------------------------
NAME1    NULL     VALUE    VALUE    NULL
NAME2    VALUE    NULL     VALUE    NULL
NAME3    VALUE    VALUE    NULL     VALUE
```

Using always the same query and just changing this `WHERE` clause
`...WHERE COLUMN1 LIKE 'NAME1';` I would want the next output

```
COLUMN1  COLUMN3  COLUMN4
-------------------------
NAME1    VALUE    VALUE
```

Another example: `...WHERE COLUMN1 LIKE 'NAME3';`

```
COLUMN1  COLUMN2  COLUMN3  COLUMN 5
-----------------------------------
NAME3    VALUE    VALUE    VALUE
```

Comment: You're testing the same column every time.

Comment: The result of a SELECT query is a table, and has to have the same number of columns in every row. What do you expect the result to be if there are different numbers of non-null columns?

Comment: The `COALESCE()` function may be helpful. `COALESCE(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)` returns the value of the first non-null column in the list.

Comment: I changed the names so it'd be generic and I forgot to change the numbers. Each row is a different column

Comment: Please, add sample data and expected output, so people are not guessing and put an answer before knowing your exact problem. This will be very helpful.

Comment: @D.Smania I hope that change helps.
Thank you all for your answers

Comment: @JesusRedondo it really helps, as you can see, none of the previous posted answer approaches your goal.

Comment: @D.Smania Yeah, I see. I was in a hurry and I thought I was not going to be aswered this quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SQL query is fixed in the columns that are returned.  So, you cannot do what you want with a simple `select` query.  You could use dynamic SQL.

However, you can only return the values that you want as a single string:

```
select name, concat_ws(',', column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6)
from t
where . . . ;
```

That said, the real issue is probably your data structure.  in general, you do not want to store such column values in a pivoted form.  Instead, include a single value per row.  In other words, you want a *junction*/*association* table with one row per value and per name.

Then the query would be:

```
select name, group_concat(value)
from association_table 
group by name;
```

Answer (score 4):

T-SQL:

```
SELECT COALESCE(column1, column2) from table
```

it select the value of the first non-null of this `column1 and column2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use IFNULL statement to check for NULL and fetch alternate column

```
SELECT IFNULL(column1,column2) value
FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: If you have many columns and want to fetch the first non-null please use @developer_29's answer as: SELECT COALESCE(column1, column2, column3) from table

Comment: THis will fetch the first column with non-null value

Comment: I have used this and checked the manual but it is not what I am looking for.